# How does the Summer's Crown ability change Quen?

Tags: the-witcher-2

By praying at a certain shrine, you obtain this ability, which changes the appearance of your Quen sign and presumably affects it favourably.

What aspects of Quen does it precisely change, beside the appearance?

Answer (score 1):

Fiery Quen has a chance to incinerate (put enemies on fire) when they hit the shield.